# Why do i keep seeing this green/blue light in my viewport?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

I just downloaded the latest blender in another PC and imported an image, the green/blue lights appear as soon as i open a new file, need help[image: full view]

Comment: Definitely a GPU/OpenGL error. Check and make sure your graphics drivers are up to date, and if that doesn't work, check your blender installation (reinstalling if necessary).

Comment: Yes! it was the reinstalling after updating the drivers that solved the issue! thank you so much!!